# For Loop: Extract values in a sequence, compute it, and return it to the same place

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I will keep this simple.

Let's assume:

```
n <- rep(seq(100, 5000, by=50), length.out=1000)
a <- NULL
```

I want to write a For Loop function that will take the same values (e.g., all 100's, all 150's, all 200's, etc.) in vector 'n' add them, and return the sum in the same order in vector 'a', such that:

```
a[1, 100, 199]
1100, 1100, 1100
a[2, 101, 200]
1650, 1650, 1650
a[99, 198, 297]
50000, 50000, 50000
```

In other words, n should contain 11 100's, 11 150's, 11 200's,..., and 10 5000's, and I want to grab similar elements, add them, and sequence the sum of similar elements in the right sequence in vector 'a'
I hope this makes sense.

Comment: You'll improve the chances someone can help by adding a tag of the language for your code.

Comment: @user2105555 This is not clear. You mentioned `a` as vector and assigned NULL to it.  I am assuming you missed to paste a line involving `a`.

Comment: @akrun. Hey Akrun. Nope, I assigned NULL so that I can fill it up with anything generated from the FOR loop.

Comment: @user2015555 But, I am confused by `a[1,100,199]` How do you define `a` and its locations?

Comment: @akrun. Ahh I see what you mean now! I totally left something out. Give me a sec..

Comment: I explained it between the code block. Let me rephrase it then.

Comment: @user2105555 Please check my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
a1 <-ave(n,n,FUN=sum)
a1[c(1,100,199)]
#[1] 1100 1100 1100

a1[c(2,101,200)]
#[1] 1650 1650 1650

a1[c(99,198,297)]
#[1] 50000 50000 50000
```

Or if you want a `lapply` solution

```
a <- unsplit(lapply(split(n,n),function(x) rep(sum(x),length(x))),n)
```